# Save datagridview data and recover from xml file#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a application where I save data from a datagridView with 3 columns  to the xml file the application has save and load buttions where when save is pressed it saves to the xml file problem is it does not load the changes made in the datagridview... Only loads the headers for it.

DATAGRIDVIEW COLUMNS : (column 1= text, column 2 =checkbox , column 3 = dropdown w) Note: The dropdown has two values... so its obvoiusly 0 and 1

Code for save :

```
public void Save(DataGridView dgv)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    for (int i = 1; i < dgv.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
    {
        DataColumn column = new DataColumn(dgv.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText);
        dt.Columns.Add(column);

    }
    int ColumnCount = dgv.Columns.Count;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dgv.Rows)
    {
        DataRow dataRow = dt.NewRow();
        for (int i = 0; i < ColumnCount; i++)
        {
            dataRow[i] = dr.Cells[i];
        }
    }
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.Tables.Add(dt);
    XmlTextWriter newXml = new XmlTextWriter(@"c:/older/DGVXML.xml", Encoding.UTF8);
    ds.WriteXmlSchema(newXml);
}
```

So far this is all I have for the load:

```
public void Load(DataGridView dgv)
{
    XmlReader xmlFile = XmlReader.Create(@"c:/older/DGVXML.xml", new XmlReaderSettings());
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    dataSet.ReadXml(xmlFile,XmlReadMode.ReadSchema);
    //LOADS!!! YAY, but only the headers with no data... check save?
    dgv.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
    xmlFile.Close();  
}
```

Comment: `Dictionary` has `Keys` collection. For each key you have to create a row in `DataGridView` and then populate row `Cells`. What is the problem?

Comment: i have no idea how to take this on...

Comment: properties are not meant for storing these kind of data. Instead persist your data in a xml file and load it whenever you need it

Comment: @thangadurai care to share how i would go about with this

Comment: What is the data source that you are using to bind? Is it a DataSet,if yes then you can use DataSet.WriteXml(filename) method to create xml file. Use DataSet.ReadXml(filename) method to read it into the DataSet

Comment: column 1= text is getting the data/rows from sql (rest of the columns are user input)                      var ds = new DataTable();
            dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
            dgv.DataSource = ds;

Comment: please check out the edit i did to the question.. now saving to an xml file instead.. but it is only saving the headings not what is in the datagridview

Comment: Which are u defining columns `AutoGenerateColumns = True` or static definition?

Comment: @Jumpei i get the data from sql for the 1st column the rest are added progrmly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# Save DataGridView to Xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43053387/c-sharp-save-datagridview-to-xml-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem  1

You have to call `dt.Rows.Add(dataRow)` to add row.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ycd1034.aspx

## Problem 2

`DataSet.WriteXmlSchema` method doesn't output current data, only structure.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kas5y1ky(v=vs.110).aspx

Use `DataSet.WriteXml` method instead.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ws09ehyc(v=vs.110).aspx

Code being used is as follows.. made changes to it (edited by question asker)

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
for (int i = 1; i < dgv.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
{
    DataColumn column = new DataColumn(dgv.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText);
    dt.Columns.Add(column);
}
int columnCount = dgv.Columns.Count;
foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dgv.Rows)
{
    DataRow dataRow = dt.NewRow();
    for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
    {
        //returns checkboxes and dropdowns as string with .value..... nearly got it
        dataRow[i] = dr.Cells[i].Value;
    }
    dt.Rows.Add(dataRow);
}
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Add(dt);
XmlTextWriter xmlSave = new XmlTextWriter(@"c:/older/DGVXML.xml", Encoding.UTF8);
           
ds.WriteXml(xmlSave);
xmlSave.Close();
```

Comment: <NewDataSet />  is all that i get in the xml file when saving

Comment: You mean you tried calling `DataSet.WriteXml' and it doesn't output current data?

Comment: yes.... when i open the xml file <NewDataSet /> is all i get in it... DATAGRIDVIEW COLUMNS : (column 1= text, column 2 =checkbox , column 3 = dropdown) valus of all these columns must be saved

Comment: with dataRow[i] = dr.Cells[i]; in the for loop returns the type and postion.... im about to try dr.Cells[i].value to see what i get....

Comment: try `dr.Cells[i].value`

Comment: only saves the 1st column values and not the rest of the columns with dr.Cells[i].value...... again DATAGRIDVIEW COLUMNS : (column 1= text, column 2 =checkbox , column 3 = dropdown)

Comment: Now you can save only 1st column in current data?

Comment: when i reload the saved xml.. (column 2 =checkbox , column 3 = dropdown) values are returned as string instead of actual check boxes and dropdowns... e.g. if the check box was checked and the datagridview is saved, when it is loaded again it returns it as a value "true" written in the cell..... hope that makes sence

Comment: It was loaded as text, you have to generate progrmly.

Comment: Try set `DataColumn.DataType`.

Answer (score 0):

You first mistake was to choose `ListDictionary` as a holder for data. Second, to *serialize* data as array of `string`.

You could have a small type presenter class to hold your data (or use `Tuple`).

```
public class MyParameter
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public bool Enabled {get; set;} // notice type
    public SomeType Direction {get; set;} // not sure in type
}
```

Then you can easily serialize rows as a list or array

```
var list = dgv.Rows.Select(o => new MyParameter()
{
    Name = o.Cells["name"],
    Enabled = o.Cells["ENABLED"],
    Direction = o.Cells["DIRECTION"]
}).ToList();
```

And restoring data will looks as simple as

```
foreach(var parameter in app.Properties.Settings.Default.DeviceSettings)
{
    dvg.Rows.Add(parameter.Name, parameter.Enabled, parameter.Direction);
}
```

Code may not compile (from head), but should give an idea.

I forgot to mention, what I never used `Properties` to store application settings (simply because they are crap). I rely on the fact, what you was able to store `Dictionary` in it, then my implementation should works as well.

Much better way to save configuration (configuration is a set of application properties) is to use, to example, `XmlSerializer` to save data in `xml` format (which is human-friendly to view/edit). The approach will still be the same to store list of settings: get them as a list, serialize (or if they are just a part of other configuration settings, assign to property and serialize whole configuration).

Comment: DATAGRIDVIEW COLUMNS : (column 1= text, column 2 =checkbox , column 3 = dropdown) note: the dropdown has two values.....  i would use a arraylist

Comment: Never use an arraylist!

Comment: looked at a different approch of saving to xml file posted it by the code.. check it out guys added coments

Comment: please check out the edit i did to the question.. now saving to an xml file instead.. but it is only saving the headings not what is in the datagridview... help with that mybe?