# Saving data from datagridview to XML and load

Tags: c#, xml, datagridview

how can i save all data from dataGridView to XML.
Now save only from textbox.
Thank you very much

> Hello together, how can i save all data from dataGridView to XML.
>   Now save only from textbox.
>   Thank you very much

```
public partial class SaveToXML : Form
{
    private XmlDocument doc;
    private XmlElement root;
    public string PATH = @"H:\\Data.xml";
    public SaveToXML()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = textBox1.Text;
        dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = textBox2.Text;
        dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = textBox3.Text;
        dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = textBox4.Text;
        dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[4].Value = textBox5.Text;
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(PATH);

        xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument();
        xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Event_Information");
        xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Data_Set_Type", "REPLACE");

        xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Service");
        xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Name", "TV");

        xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Event");
        xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Start", textBox1.Text + " " + textBox2.Text);
        xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Duration", textBox3.Text);

        xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("short-event-descriptor");
        xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Language", "deu");
        xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Name");
        xmlWriter.WriteString(textBox4.Text);
        xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
        xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();

        xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("extended-event-descriptor");
        xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Language", "deu");
        xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Text");
        xmlWriter.WriteString(textBox5.Text);
        xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();

        xmlWriter.WriteEndDocument();

        xmlWriter.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Try this DataSet ds = (DataSet) dataGridView1.DataSource;
 ds.WriteXml("path");

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# Save DataGridView to Xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43053387/c-sharp-save-datagridview-to-xml-file)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Store
    DataSet ds = (DataSet) dataGridView1.DataSource;
    ds.WriteXml("path");

    //Load
    string path = @"path";
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.ReadXml(path);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
}
```