# How to add XML child nodes to parent node c#

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

How to add XML child nodes to parent node c#

> My current xml file looks like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding=""?>
<sheet1>


  <rd>
    <id>45</id>
    <name>alex</name>
    <last>chali</last>
    <phone>33666998565</phone>
    <refF>
      <adresse>41301 US Hwy 280, Sylacauga AL 35150</adresse>
      <citie>NY</citie>
    </refF>
    <age>30</age>
    <mp>
      <degree>2</degree>
    </mp>
    <dpa>1</dpa>
  </rd>
  <rd>
    <id>89</id>
    <name>anna</name>
    <last>marie</last>
    <phone>336465798465</phone>
    <refF>
      <adresse>30 Memorial Drive, Avon MA 2322</adresse>
      <citie>LA</citie>
    </refF>
    <age>28</age>
    <mp>
      <degree>2</degree>
    </mp>
    <dpa>1</dpa>
  </rd>

</sheet1>
```

> What am looking for:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding=""?>
<sheet1>

**<table>  // i want that contain all table rows**

  <rd>
    <id>45</id>
    <name>alex</name>
    <last>chali</last>
    <phone>33666998565</phone>
    <refF>
      <adresse>41301 US Hwy 280, Sylacauga AL 35150</adresse>
      <citie>NY</citie>
    </refF>
    <age>30</age>
    <mp>
      <degree>2</degree>
    </mp>
    <dpa>1</dpa>
  </rd>

  **</table>**
</sheet1>
```

> This is my code:

```
  string header = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?><Sheet1></Sheet1>";
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(header);
            XElement sheet1 = doc.Root;

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.AsEnumerable())
            {
                XElement rd = new XElement("rd", new object[] {
                    new XElement("id", row["id"]),
                    new XElement("name", row["name"]),
                    new XElement("last", row["last"]),
                    new XElement("phone", row["phone"]),
                    new XElement("refF", new object[] {
                        new XElement("adresse", row["adresse"]),
                        new XElement("citie", row["citie"]),
                    }),
                    new XElement("age", row["age"]),
                    new XElement("mp", new XElement("degree", row["mp"])),
                    new XElement("dpa", row["dpa"])
                });

                sheet1.Add(rd);
            }

            doc.Save(FILENAME);

        }
```

The code shows 'sheet1' as a root elements which include 'rd', but actually i want it as a child elements inside 'table. How should i re-structure that? Note, i can only use xDocument not xmlDocument

Comment: From : <Sheet1></Sheet1> To : <table></table>  I was wondering if you were going to ask this question.  If you want both Sheet1 and table then <Sheet1><table></table><Sheet1>  Then XElement table = doc.Descendants("table").First();  finally add rows to table From : sheet1.Add(rd); To : table.Add(rd);

Comment: Yeah that was what what am looking for now my issue is with save button

Comment: You already have a save method.  So if you declare doc in global space you can simply do the doc.Save(FILENAME) inside the button click.

Comment: Now i want the button shows save dialog and choose the path of saving the xml file

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-save-files-using-the-savefiledialog-component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - You could add `table` tag to the `header` like:

```
string header = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?><Sheet1><table></table></Sheet1>";
```

2 - Instead getting  `Root`, get the `table` element like :

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(header);
XElement table = doc.Root.Element("table");
```

**Result**

```
string header = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?><Sheet1><table></table></Sheet1>";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(header);
XElement table = doc.Root.Element("table");

foreach (DataRow row in dt.AsEnumerable())
{
    XElement rd = new XElement("rd", new object[] {
        new XElement("id", row["id"]),
        new XElement("name", row["name"]),
        new XElement("last", row["last"]),
        new XElement("phone", row["phone"]),
        new XElement("refF", new object[] {
            new XElement("adresse", row["adresse"]),
            new XElement("citie", row["citie"]),
        }),
        new XElement("age", row["age"]),
        new XElement("mp", new XElement("degree", row["mp"])),
        new XElement("dpa", row["dpa"])
    });

    table.Add(rd);
}
doc.Save(FILENAME);
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much. This was a great solution and worked perfectly.
I have another small problem if you can help me solve it?

Comment: @Uzarsef you're welcome, i can help. explain to me what's the problem.

Comment: i want to create a button to export data from datagridview to this xml file and don't have dataset its only a table import from excel to datatable

Comment: @Uzarsef, unfortunately, i don't know a lot of about manipulation of dataGridView, but i think you search something like this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/43055506/1745795, i hope this help you.